# What is the gitignore equivalent of "one or more occurrence"?

Tags: regex, r, git

While working with R, Rstudio creates all these files:

**.Rhistory

.Rapp.history

.Rproj.user/**

I want git to ignore these files so I put them in .gitignore, and to do it in one line I use

```
*.R*
```

but it will also ignore actual **.R** files which I don't want. So I tried the below regexes,

```
*.R.+
```

and

```
*.R+
```

but I guess there is some other equivalent for dot (. for single character match) or plus (+ for one or more occurrences of previous letter) in gitignore which I am unaware of. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: is this glob or regex?

Comment: Insert them manually, no special pattern here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Glob, `*` matches any amount of characters.

Comment: @dystroy Not so many types, but the reason I posted it is because it looks simple but I am unable to figure out the right regex for this in gitignore.

Comment: @MarounMaroun pattern is there. all files that have .R+ extension i.e. having one or more character preceding R preceding dot(.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you need to use `?` . `?` in glob matches any single character.

```
*.R?*
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

`*`

Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a filename expansion context, two adjacent ‘*’s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a ‘/’, two adjacent ‘*’s will match only directories and subdirectories.

`?`

Matches any single character.

Comment: What `.*R(?!$)` will look like in glob?

Comment: `*R?*` . `?` here asserts that there must be a single character exists after R

Comment: So, for example, if one wants to only check in `.env`, as that is the normal file used for production, and inside a repo it should only contains dummy examples anyway, then one would add a gitignore of `.env?*` to match any dev/test env files that need to be excluded as they are only used for dev/test purposes. `?` means it must match 1 char more after the `.env` and then it can contains 0 or more other chars (`.env.local`, `.env.development`, `.envB`, `.envBlah`, etc.)